# Fedora - Xampp starting Apache fails

Tags: fedora, xampp

I'm trying to install Xampp on `Fedora Linux 35`, but I'm getting this error every time I try to start it.

I followed [this tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-xampp-on-fedora/)

command I use -
`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Output -

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 8.0.6-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
httpd: Syntax error on line 522 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_perl.so into server: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
```

I tried reinstalling, but it didn't help. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error message you miss `libnsl` library. So try to install it:

```
yum install libnsl
```